# How to make clap ignore a specific field in a struct?

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments, clap

I'm building my Rust CLI with clap.

I have one `struct` with all the command line options. This struct is passed through to a lot of functions.

Now I would like to add a field to this struct, but not surface this field as a command line argument. I don't want to pass through an additional struct just for a single field.

Is there some clap syntax that allows clap to ignore a field in the struct, and just set it to some default?

This is a sample struct:

```
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
pub struct AlignPairwiseParams {
  #[clap(long)]
  #[clap(default_value_t = AlignPairwiseParams::default().min_length)]
  pub min_length: usize,

  // I would like this field to be not surface through the CLI. How to do this?
  pub internal_use_only: bool,
}
```

Does something like `#[clap(ignore)]` exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the derive reference](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/v3.1.18/examples/derive_ref/README.md#arg-attributes):

> #### Arg Attributes
>
> - ...
> - `skip [= <expr>]`: Ignore this field, filling in with `<expr>`
>
>   - Without `<expr>`: fills the field with `Default::default()`

So `#[clap(skip)]`.